# mysql cumulate till meet condition for different subject

Tags: php, mysql

I'm fairly new to this, meet another learning curve.
Here's the table

```
id  
item  
date  
quantity
```

Here's the objective.
I want to find out the number of days it will take for the quantity to add up to meet a target figure, starting the next day.

Example:

Target figure 5

```
Day 1:  
item(1), quantity(0)  
item(2), quantity(2)  
item(3), quantity(5)  

Day 2:  
item(1), quantity(4)  
item(2), quantity(7)  
item(3), quantity(0)  

Day 3:  
item(1), quantity(2)  
item(2), quantity(1)  
item(3), quantity(0)
```

So it will take 3 days for `item(1)` to reach 5, 2 days for `item(2)` to reach 5, 1 day for `item(3)` to reach 5.

It would be absolutely wonderful to achieve this completely within MySQL.
For now, I can only do this in PHP with a counter, which is quite primitive.

Comment: Please provide some of your current code, SQL or PHP, that you are using to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  Item, MIN(DT), MIN(noDays) noDays
FROM    (
    SELECT  i.Item, i.DT, COUNT(DISTINCT i2.DT) noDays, SUM(i2.Quantity) [Sum]
    FROM    #items i
    INNER   JOIN #items i2 ON i2.Item = i.Item AND i.ID >= i2.ID
    GROUP   BY i.Item, i.DT
) main
WHERE [SUM] >= 5
GROUP BY Item
```

Assuming your table is ordered by date.

Comment: This works! Holy... Then it comes the tricker part. For each record that has a quantity of zero (0), there's no actual record. But the missing days still count. Do I check against a calendar table? Order was a concern as well, but for now I just use an index.

Comment: Do you have a specific start date? A start date for each item?  If each item had it's own start date, you could have a table with 2 columns (Item|StartDate).  Then do a DATEDIFF(day,startdate,enddate) AS noDays to get the number of days, where enddate is the date you get from the original answer.  If the start date is fixed then you can set it yourself.

Comment: That solves! MySQL is getting more powerful to me each time I learn sth about it. Thanks!